# What does this syntax (int a : 42;) mean?

Tags: c++

Recently I came about code like this in the `<QMap>` header.

```
#include <iostream>

class Something
{
public:
    int a : 42;   // What does this mean?
};

int main()
{
    Something something;
    std::cout << something.a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It does not seem to be initialization, since the program outputs `0`.

Also I get a strange warning:

```
main.cpp:6: warning: width of 'Something::a' 
exceeds its type [enabled by default]
```

Comment: @milleniumbug: or a tentative of a bitfield, since `int` typically only has 32 bits so 42 won't fit.